# Using ContentSecuirtyPolicy and nonce values in CodeIgniter 4.x

Tags: php, content-security-policy, codeigniter-4, nonce

When you turn content security policy on in .env via "app.CSPEnabled = true" a nonce is created for every inline css and javascript for the debug bar but NOT for the kint inline script and inline styles. I can see the  {csp-style-nonce} text in the welcome page view file. The welcome page has styles and scripts with no nonce. My browser complains about these but doesn't complain about the kint js and css. Why?

How is the browser told what the nonce values should be? There are several. More than one for styles and more than one for scripts. If I use the CI feature  {csp-style-nonce} and  {csp-script-nonce} don't I also have to tell the browser about it in a Content-Security_Policy header? How do I do that for each nonce

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ContentSecurityPolicy.php` class for CI4 has a bug - it [generates](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/HTTP/ContentSecurityPolicy.php#L592) a new 'nonce' value for each inline style/script. Although several 'nonce-value' in the same directive [are supported](https://csplite.com/csp/test159/), this is inconvenient and redundant.
That approach should be used for `'hash-value'`, which must be generated for each embedded script and style individually, but not for `'nonce'`.

As you can see in the `ContentSecurityPolicy.php` code, each  `{csp-style-nonce}` and `{csp-script-nonce}` helpers in the HTML:

```
<script {csp-script-nonce}>
    // ...
</script>

<style {csp-style-nonce}>
  /* ... */
</style>
```

are substituted with `nonce='new_generated_value'` and that `new_generated_value` is added into `$this->scriptSrc[]` / `$this->styleSrc[]` array respectively.

Arrays `$this->scriptSrc[]` and `$this->styleSrc[]` are used to craft whitelist for `script-src` and `style-src` directives in the  Content-Security-Policy HTTP response header.
Thus, all inline scripts/styles had get the 'nonce="value_xxx"` attribute , and all values of 'nonce-value_xxx' are inserted into the corresponding CSP directive in the HTTP header.

This should work, although generating so many nonce values doesn't make sense.